# How to make date command work in relation to custom specified date?

Tags: linux, bash, date, environment-variables, zsh

In Linux there is pretty awesome command **date** which can be used is ways like this:

```
# Get some cool date in relation to systems date:
date  -d "last Sunday -7 days"
Sun Sep 15 00:00:00 PDT 2013

# Set systems date:
date --set="2013-03-04"
Mon Mar  4 00:00:00 PST 2013
```

Basically I want to be able to run this command like this:

```
date --date="last Sunday -7 days" +%Y-%m-%d
2013-09-15
```

But not in relation to today's system date but in relation to some date generated by another computation in the form of string (e.g. "2013-09-01") or something else.

Please help me to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a function:

```
function get_last_day {
    local date=$1 day=$2 format=$3 a b i
    for (( i = 0; i <= 6; ++i )); do
        read -r a b < <(exec date -d "$date - $i days" "+%a $format")
        if [[ $a == "$day" ]]; then
            echo "$b"
            return
        fi
    done
}

get_last_day '2013-09-18' Sun '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Output:

```
2013-09-15
```

Comment: thanks, but is there any way to get this working:

date -d '2013-09-18 last Sunday' +%Y-%m-%d

which which would return 2013-09-15

Comment: well, thanks I was looking for some elegant approach, but looks like I'll have write a python script anyways.